# How to Apply Conditional Format to show a field is mandatory to be filled in based on a vlookup to another sheet

Tags: excel, ms-office, formula, vlookup, conditional-formatting

I'm trying to create a form in excel for my team to fill out which highlights certain cells in a row as compulsory (format the cell colour) based on the number from a table in another sheet which has **3 preset dimensions** `("M"=Mandatory, "P"=Prohibited, "O"=Optional)` for each number across multiple analysis field.

I have tried conditional formatting formulas to highlight the cell to fill out if the lookup of the number chosen returns "M") but I don't seem to have a formula which validated this and returns with the cell highlighted when it needs to completed.

[image: Imgur]

[image: Imgur]

I would like the formula to return the cell as highlighted if it is mandatory based on the lookup to the table and need the user to fill out the cell with the information relevant.

Any help would be much appreciated.

Comment: Can you please [edit your question](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/56172666/edit) to provide sample data, expected outcome, and the formulas you have tried so far? You can upload screen caps to http://imgur.com and link to then

Answer (score 0):

If I understand your question correctly you just want the cell to highlight when its sister cell in another sheet is coded "M". That's a fairly easy formula.

=Sheet2!$B1="M"

This is for a straight column in B, where the cell it's checking against is in sheet 2 and also in column B. If it's for a row simply move the $ to say b$1.

If you want the highlight to disappear when the cell is filled in use this formula:

=AND($B1=0,Sheet2!$B1="M")